# Oracle to Sql server: how to reproduce this select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a select statement that works in oracle. This is an imitation of how it looks like (the real statement is 200+ lines):

```
select * from (
    select * from (
            select id, name from my_table where name like 'D%' or name like 'Z%' order by name, id)
            union all
    select * from (
            select id, name from my_table where name like 'K%' or name like 'T%' order by name, id)
            union all
    select * from (
            select id, name from my_table where name like 'B%' or name like 'M%' order by name, id)
);
```

So, basially it's a union of 3 types of records from the same table. The outer "select * from" is automatically added and cannot be removed/changed. The ordering is important - records from the first subquery must be first, then records from the second one etc.

I need to rewrite it for sql server (preferably one common statement that works in oracle and sql server as well, but it's optional)

What I tried was:

```
select * from (
    select * from (
            select id, name, 1 as order_column from my_table where name like 'D%' or name like 'Z%') subquery
            union all
    select * from (
            select id, name, 2 as order_column from my_table where name like 'K%' or name like 'T%') subquery
            union all
    select * from (
            select id, name, 3 as order_column from my_table where name like 'B%' or name like 'M%') subquery
) outerquery order by order_column, name, id;
```

The ordering is preserved, but the order_column is included in result records and that is wrong.

So I changed it into:

```
select * from (
    select id, name from (
            select id, name, 1 as order_column from my_table where name like 'D%' or name like 'Z%') subquery
            union all
    select id, name from (
            select id, name, 2 as order_column from my_table where name like 'K%' or name like 'T%') subquery
            union all
    select id, name from (
            select id, name, 3 as order_column from my_table where name like 'B%' or name like 'M%') subquery
) parentquery order by order_column, name, id
```

But now, obviously the order_column is not visible in the outer query and it doesn't work. As I wrote before the "select * from" in first line cannot be changed - only the outer ORDER BY clause. Also the example conditions "name like 'D%'" are much more complex in reality and I cannot use them in some kind of outer order by ... case when ... (they must stay in subqueries)

I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Why woiuld you expect the column `Order_column` to *not* be displayed? You're using `SELECT *`... If you only want to return specific columns, then don't use `*`, list the columns out you need.

Comment: "The outer "select * from" is automatically added and cannot be removed/changed". I am trying to return only name and id and cannot select anything but * in outer query.

Comment: Automatically added by what? Like I said, `*` returns every column in the dataset. You need to list your columns; there is no other answer here. There is no such syntax as `SELECT *(EXCEPT order_column)`. if you can't change the way the statement is generated, you need to speak to whomever can. The statement is working exactly as it should be.

Comment: The company framework I am using wraps every query in "select * from (...) t" It cannot be changed and I can only add outer ORDER BY clause to this. There weren't be any problem if i could just change the selected columns.

Comment: Then you'll have to fix your display layer to not include the column. Either way, the application is the problem, not the SQL.

Comment: Still, the problem included in this question is about how to change the sql statement while maintaining the listed conditions. Comments like "change your system" aren't really helpful. Still, thank you for your answers.

Comment: You can't. If you exclude `order_column` in your subquery you then can't include it in the `ORDER BY`, meaning that if you exclude the `ORDER BY` the order is random, and if you can't change `*` to a list of columns then you have to have it (`order_column`) in the return dataset. It's one or the other.

Comment: Yes. This basically sums up what I wrote in my question. That is why I am looking for alternate solution that will provide me with the same outcome. Gordon Linoff's answer was pretty close but unfortunately I cannot use subquery conditions in case/when clause.

Answer (score 2):

Neither database guarantees the ordering of the result set without an `order by`.

Why not just do this in either database?

```
select id, name, 1 as order_column
from my_table
where name like 'D%' or name like 'Z%' or
      name like 'K%' or name like 'T%' or
      name like 'B%' or name like 'M%'    
order by (case when name like 'D%' or name like 'Z%' then 1
               when name like 'K%' or name like 'T%' then 2
               when name like 'B%' or name like 'M%' then 3
          end)
```

In SQL Server, you can simplify this to:

```
select id, name, 1 as order_column
from my_table
where name like '[DZKTBM]%'  
order by (case when name like '[DZ]%' then 1
               when name like '[KT]%' then 2
               when name like '[BM]%' then 3
          end)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But the UNION ALL must stay and as I wrote: " Also the example conditions "name like 'D%'" are much more complex in reality and I cannot use them in some kind of outer "order by ... case when ..." (they must stay in subqueries)"

Comment: @Jakubeeee . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you actually ask.  This answers your question and is better than the query in your question.  If you have *another* question, then ask the question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and a good explanation of what you want to accomplish.